# Запускаю из одной Java программы вторую. Почему не могу прочитать из первой программы выходной поток второй

Tags: java

Оба класса предварительно скомпилировал. Запускаю FromWhich.java и ожидаю увидеть на экране ответ "Hello World"

```
public class FromWhich {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = "CMD /C java WhichToStart";

    Process process = runtime.exec(cmd.split(" "));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class WhichToStart {
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WhichToStart().start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делал примерно так:

```
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*вписать нужное*/);
    final ProcessResultReader stderr = new ProcessResultReader(p.getErrorStream(), "STDERR");
    final ProcessResultReader stdout = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream(), "STDOUT");
    stderr.start();
    stdout.start();
    final int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    System.out.print(stdout.toString());
    System.err.print(stderr.toString());

class ProcessResultReader extends Thread {
    final InputStream is;
    final String type;
    final StringBuilder sb;

    ProcessResultReader(final InputStream is, String type) {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, по сути это такой же код. Не могли бы пожалуйста привести код вызываемой программы, которая что - н вернет. Как она должна выглядеть и нужно ли в ней(во второй, вызываемой программе) перенаправлять потоки вывода каким-то образом, чтобы вызывающая их смогла обработать?

Comment: пример вызова сверху, ничего перенаправлять не надо, просто вывод в консоль.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что достаю Вас, но что нужно указывать тут:             final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*вписать нужное*/);   на месте /*вписать нужное*/ , интуиция подсказывает, что дело именно в этом.

Comment: да что угодно... `java ClassToStart` к примеру.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class ProcessResultReader extends Thread
{
    final InputStream is;
    final String type;
    final StringBuilder sb;

    /**
     *
     * @param is
     * @param type
     */
    ProcessResultReader( final InputStream is,  String type)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                this.sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Верхний класс используется снизу

```
package main.java.utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ProcessManager {

    private ProcessResultReader stderrReader;
    private ProcessResultReader stdoutReader;

    private Process p;

    public int exitCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public String command;

    public ProcessManager(String command) {
        this.command = command;
        this.stderrReader = null;
        this.stdoutReader = null;

    }

    private void runCommand(boolean waitEnding, long timeout, boolean isCmd, File dir) {
        try {
            if (isCmd)
                if (dir != null)
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", command), null, dir);
                else
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", command));

            else if (dir != null)
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, dir);
                else
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


            stderrReader = new ProcessResultReader(p.getErrorStream(), "STDERR");
            stdoutReader = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream(), "STDOUT");
            stderrReader.start();
            stdoutReader.start();

            if (waitEnding)
                exitCode = p.waitFor();

            if (timeout > 0)
                p.waitFor(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Messages.getInstance().fatal(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (waitEnding)
                p.destroy();
            //assertEquals("Process exit code not valid!", 0, exitCode);
        }
    }

    public void runCommand(long timeout) {
        this.runCommand(true, timeout, true, null);
    }

    public void runCommand() {
        this.runCommand(true, 0, true, null);
    }
    public void runCommand(File workingDir) {
        this.runCommand(true, 0, true, workingDir);
    }

    public void runCommand(boolean waitEnding, boolean isCmd) {
        this.runCommand(waitEnding, 0, isCmd, null);
    }

    public void runCommand(boolean waitEnding, boolean isCmd, File workingDir) {
        this.runCommand(waitEnding, 0, isCmd, workingDir);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        p.destroy();
    }

    public String getStdout() {
        if (stdoutReader != null) {
            return stdoutReader.sb.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getStdError() {
        if (stderrReader != null) {
            return stderrReader.sb.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

ПРимеры:

```
ProcessManager pm = new ProcessManager("ping 8.8.8.8");
pm.runCommand(true, true);
String sb = processManager.getStdout() + processManager.getStdError();

 ProcessManager pm = new ProcessManager("java WhichToStart");
 pm.runCommand(true, false);
 String sb = processManager.getStdout() + processManager.getStdError();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FromWhich {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("CMD /C java -cp ./ WhichToStart.class".split(" "));
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```